# 'troppo poche' vs. 'troppe poche'

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gender

> Il linguaggio richiede di essere accordato come il violino. Troppe o troppe poche parole guastano il messaggio.

È corretto scrivere 'Troppe o **troppe** poche parole', o dovrebbe essere 'Troppe o **troppo** poche parole'?

Comment: Diciamo così: se sai come e quando farlo, cioè se parli un italiano super-colto, e ti stai rivolgendo ad una persona che può capirti e apprezzare, anche nell'italiano moderno ti puoi permettere di concordare "troppo" con il sostantivo che lo segue (come suggerisce I.M. giù): credo che sia uno di quegli aspetti belli della lingua, la possibilità di recuperare usi antichi e riapplicarli dove si ritiene opportuno, spesso con ironia. In caso contrario, se hai la minima incertezza, è meglio evitare perché nell'italiano moderno è generalmente considerato un errore come evidenziato da Walter Tross.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Corretto è:

> Troppe o troppo poche parole

*Troppo* è avverbio di *poche*, e, in quanto avverbio, è invariabile. *Troppe* e *poche* invece sono aggettivi di *parole*, con cui devono concordare in genere e numero.

La concordanza in genere e numero tra avverbio e aggettivo (e quindi, transitivamente, tra avverbio e sostantivo) è, nell'italiano corrente, percepita come del tutto scorretta. Ciò non toglie che l'errore venga commesso, come tanti altri errori di concordanza. Quando viene commesso, però, l'effetto è che, proprio a causa della concordanza, l'avverbio viene recepito come un ulteriore aggettivo.

Nel caso di *troppe poche* si può dire che *tropp-* entra nella frase come avverbio, e ne esce come aggettivo. Il parlante in questo caso commette un "eccesso di concordanza", che è possibile commettere soltanto con quegli avverbi che coincidono con il singolare maschile di un aggettivo. Ad esempio, non è possibile fare lo stesso errore con l'avverbio *meno*.

Comment: D'accordo su quasi tutto, ma formalmente non direi che «l'effetto [dell'errore] è che, proprio a causa della concordanza, l'avverbio viene recepito come un ulteriore aggettivo», semmai è l'errata concordanza a essere un effetto del fatto che si percepisce “troppo” come un aggettivo; e questo per il semplice motivo che è impossibile concordare un avverbio, non essendo dotato di numero o genere.

Comment: @DaG: sì e no: nella struttura profonda, per il parlante, _tropp-_ resta comunque un avverbio. Subisce però il trattamento di un aggettivo per quello che ho chiamato, nell'aggiunta alla mia risposta, "eccesso di concordanza".

Answer (score 2):

*Troppo*, seguito da un aggettivo, si usa come avverbio, quindi invariabile.

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/troppo/):

> Pur avendo valore avverbiale o di pron. neutro, **nell’uso ant. o pop.** è a volte concordato nel genere e nel numero col sostantivo seguente: *sua moglie è troppa superba; l’altra* [chiave] *vuol troppa D’arte e d’ingegno avanti che diserri* (Dante); *da capo, presa una gran pietra, con troppi maggior colpi che prima fieramente cominciò a percuoter la porta* (Boccaccio).

In questo caso, però, la traduzione della citazione è sbagliata. La forma corretta [sarebbe](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-citazioni/L/linguaggio.shtml):

> Il linguaggio richiede d'essere accordato come un violino: e proprio come troppe o troppo poche vibrazioni nella voce d'un cantante o nel tremolio d'una corda daranno la nota falsa, così troppe o troppo poche parole defrauderanno il messaggio.
>   WILDE, Oscar (1854-1900)
>   *De Profundis*

Comment: sì, ma in settecento anni forse l'italiano è un po' cambiato :-)

Comment: @mau Già. :) Per questo ho sottolineato "nell'uso antico". Ho anche trovato la citazione corretta.

Comment: e allora mettiamoci anche [l'originale](http://books.google.it/books?id=xZMq79CoYdoC&pg=PA102&dq=%22Language+requires+to+be+tuned,+like+a+violin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pSJNU7HZMILFtQbFlIHYCg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Language%20requires%20to%20be%20tuned%2C%20like%20a%20violin%22&f=false)

Comment: Quanto a “citazione sbagliata”: semmai è la *traduzione* della citazione a essere corretta o sbagliata. (Grazie a @WalterTross per l'originale.)

Comment: @DaG Grazie. Infatti, pensavo che la citazione più corta possa essere derivata da quella originale. Cioè, è un errore di "semplificazione", non di traduzione.